# Laravel + VueJs: MPA architecture

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've created a website using Laravel+VueJs.

And there is a little issue in my understanding about which architecture of routing is better to use.
Now this app has the following structure:

- Routing system is provided by Laravel;
- Javascript files that include VueJs framework are divided into files for **each** html page (e.g: products page loads products.js from public/js folder and so on... )

That system works fine, each web page is loading lib.js file which contains every library or frameworks needed for frontend. It has around 700KB when minified by the webpack. Then we have smaller javascript files (2-3 KB each) for each web page. In general, each page loads 2-3 javascript files.

In conclusion, I wanted to know if it is a good architecture and whether should I consider to use it in the future or should I use a different type of structure. If it's not a good option, then which would be the best choise and what technology / plugin should I use?

Comment: This question is very broad and I doubt that you'll get a satisfying answer on SO. Theres no "general good" approach to this, your best solution is usually dependent on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you app is going to be `SPA` I advice you to :

- use laravel routing for API
- use [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) for your application
  navigation